# how to use different profile for dev and production in office vsto add-in development

Tags: vsto

When we dev/test our add-in, we need to request request http://dev.xx.com. and after release, in production we need to change the url to http://prod.xx.com.

How can we do this?

===

I'm new to vsto development  and c#.  I looked config file(in fact Settings.settings) way. But in fact  i don't want the users to "config" it.  It't better if I can build out two different versions in one click ervery time,  and give one to testers and another to the end user.

When I devloping server-side springboot applications, I use 3 different config file and one single jar. And give the different config file and same sigle jar to different persons.  This way at least we can confirm that the applicaiton (jar) is the same for test and deploy.

But the "Settings.settings" seems binded to the "solution" in vs. The pre processor seems not good enough, seems that it binded to the "solution" too. I have to change it in the "Properties" every time before I build the project?  Or I need to create more "Solutions"?

Maybe I did't look that deep enough, I will keep looking

=== SOLVED

We finaly solved (partly) using Conditional compilation

```
#if DEBUG
    const string baseUrl = "192.168.20.101:8001/api";
#endif

#if (!DEBUG)
    const string baseUrl = "xxx.com/api";
#endif
```

one small issue is that we need to distribute debug package to our test team.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve that, what have you tried, what is the problem? Depending on the requirements, you can use conditional compilation directives, config files, registry entries and so on...

Comment: Thanks to the comment. I added some comment in the question.

Comment: It looks like your question is not related to `vsto` add-ins. Are you developing an office (web) add-in? Have a look at the existing tags and their (long) description, I'm not sure which one is better.

Comment: Yes I am developing a vsto add-in, in c#.  not the js one.